# .Net TPL: Limited Concurrency Level Task scheduler with task priority?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am currently using the LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler detailed here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx

I want to enhance this so that individuals tasks can be assigned priority. These priorities need not map to thread priority. It should only influence the order in which tasks are started.

Does anyone know of an example of such a task scheduler? (a lot of the scheduling stuff is over my head so it would be great if there was an existing solution)

Comment: That scheduler uses a LinkedList<Task> for a queue. Try changing it to a SortedList<T> where T is a struct that holds a Task and an integer for priority, and sort the list on T.Priority.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman - [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) may not be an ideal solution - the keys (priorities) have to be unique. Most priority systems only have a few levels, and allow multiple items to be assigned the same priority

Comment: it is a bad idea. A queue having internally a set (array) of queues - one for every priority - is a better way. Priorities are not unique and limited to a small number of them. Also do not use a linked list - I have a "queue" that internally uses arrays of 4096 elements, plus opointers. a lot less allocation - items are removed from the front "page", added to the nd. Lesss allocations, less garbage to collect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: good point. Somehow I was thinking SortedList could have duplicate keys. Senior moment...

Comment: If you are interested for a `PrioritySemaphore` with async-only API, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474370/semaphoreslim-await-priority/62237447#62237447).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [Parallel Extensions Extras Samples.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples) already provide such a scheduler, the QueuedTaskScheduler. This scheduler provides priorities, concurrency limits, fairness and fine-grained control over the type and priorities of the threads used. Of course, you don't have to use or configure the features you don't need.

Stephen Toub provides a brief description of the various schedulers in the Parallel Extensions Extras [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx)

To use the QueuedTaskScheduler, you call its ActivateNewQueue method with the priority you need. This method returns a new TaskScheduler-derived Queue object managed by the parent TaskScheduler. All tasks that use a specific queue are scheduled by the parent TaskScheduler according to their priorities.

The following code creates a scheduler with a maximum concurrency level of 4, two priority queues and schedules a task on the first queue:

```
QueuedTaskScheduler qts = new QueuedTaskScheduler(TaskScheduler.Default,4);
TaskScheduler pri0 = qts.ActivateNewQueue(priority: 0);
TaskScheduler pri1 = qts.ActivateNewQueue(priority: 1);

Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{ }, 
                      CancellationToken.None, 
                      TaskCreationOptions.None, 
                      pri0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some sorted or priority data structure for the task list. Then create your own add that takes in the Priority. This may not be as good as others but it will prioritize Tasks List. You can reuse 99% of the code there. Simply replace LinkedList with a Sorted list or use LINQ to sort and write a method add that takes the priority.