# How to make concurrent requests without creating multiple threads?

Tags: c#

Can someone please show how to make concurrent requests without creating multiple threads? E.g., I want a program that makes 100 web requests and I don't want more than 8 concurrent requests at any time. I don't want to create 8 threads for the 8 concurrent requests. When a thread makes an async request, the same thread can then be used to make the next request, and so on. I am sorry but I can't wrap my head around this, and would like to see the best solution out there. In case it wasn't clear, the requests I am talking about are async. I want to see a solution that does not use any locks, and uses the built-in classes to do the work.

This is some code I came up with but it does not do what it is supposed to do.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            var outstandingRequests = 0;
                            var requestCount = 0;
                            var tasks = new List<Task>(concurrentRequests);
                            while (requestCount < maxRequests)
                            {
                                if (outstandingRequests < concurrentRequests)
                                {
                                    tasks.Add(svc.GetDataAsync());  // a method that makes an async request
                                    Interlocked.Increment(ref outstandingRequests);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);                                                                       
                                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref outstandingRequests);
                                    Interlocked.Increment(ref requestCount);
                                }
                            }
                            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                        }).Wait();
```

Output:

```
[] 1 Sending Request...Received Response 490,835.00 bytes in 15.6 sec
[] 2 Sending Request...
[] 3 Sending Request...
[] 4 Sending Request...
[] 5 Sending Request...
[] 6 Sending Request...
[] 7 Sending Request...
[] 8 Sending Request...
[] 9 Sending Request...
```

I have set `concurrentRequests` to 5, so there is some bug in above code as it is making 8 requests in parallel. Initially it made only 5 requests in parallel, but as soon as one request completed, it fired off 4 more requests (should have fired off only one more).

Had to fix some bugs, but it all works out now:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            var outstandingRequests = 0;
                            var requestCount = 0;
                            // adding and removing from a List<> at the same time is not thread-safe,
                            // so have to use a SynchronizedCollection<>
                            var tasks = new SynchronizedCollection<Task>();
                            while (requestCount < maxRequests)
                            {
                                if (outstandingRequests < concurrentRequests)
                                {
                                    tasks.Add(svc.GetDataAsync(uri)); // this will be your method that makes async web call and returns a Task to signal completion of async call
                                    Interlocked.Increment(ref outstandingRequests);
                                    Interlocked.Increment(ref requestCount);
                                }
                                else
                                {                                    
                                    **tasks.Remove(await Task.WhenAny(tasks));**
                                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref outstandingRequests);                                    
                                }
                            }
                            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                        }).Wait();
```

If there is a better way to do it, please let me know.

Comment: "without creating multiple threads" and "when a thread makes an async request, the same thread can be then used to make the next request" are conflicting statements.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are trying to reinvent the thread pool. Don't do that - just use existing functionality: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx
Or you can use async versions of request methods - they are based on the thread pool too.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>How about this:</strike>

```
Parallel.Invoke (new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 },
    svcs.Select (svc => svc.GetDataAsync ()).ToArray ()) ;
```

There is a sample Microsoft implementation of a limited-concurrency task scheduler [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx). See SO questions [System.Threading.Tasks - Limit the number of concurrent Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898609/system-threading-tasks-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-tasks) and [.Net TPL: Limited Concurrency Level Task scheduler with task priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315937/net-tpl-limited-concurrency-level-task-scheduler-with-task-priority).

Comment: thanks. its useful to know. i have not tried it out. but will this not create 8 threads vs. single thread in my approach? is there some monitoring tool to know how many threads an app is creating?

Comment: It shouldn't if your async code is written correctly, i.e. is not hogging threads. Your own code above is essentially a re-implementation of Parallel.Invoke. There are performance counters to monitor the number of both OS threads and managed threads in `.NET CLR LocksAndThreads' category.

Comment: OK, tried it and this does not work. You could try it yourself. What happens is that all the async calls will get fired all at once. 

                        Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = concurrentRequests },
                        () =>
                        {
                            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, maxRequests))
                            {
                                tasks.Add(MakeRequest(uri));
                            }
                        });
                        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

Comment: You *wrote* your code to fire all tasks at once! You are only feeding one action into Parallel.Invoke, small wonder it's not helping you any. However I was mistaken about Parallel.Invoke, it takes Actions not Tasks, which is not what you want. Please refer to the SO questions I cited in my answer.

Comment: you are correct. I modified the code so that I am feeding N actions into Parallel.Invoke. Each action is an async call. But the same thing happens. All N calls are made concurrently. So MaxDegreeOfParallelism is limiting the # of threads being created; it does not limit the # of Actions it will execute concurrently. Try it out.

Comment: Yes, I've said above that Parallel.Invoke is not what you want. Use the solution from the first SO question referred to in my answer.